# Mountain Lion update and mercurial libraries python

Tags: python, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I updated the mac to Mountain Lion (10.8) and now the project I developed with Python and Google App Engine does not work.

GAE libraries are found, while standard Python libraries (are these Python libraries?) are missed (e.g. `cgi`, `logging`, `json`).

When I open eclipse (which has PyDeV) I receive this alert:

```
abort: couldn't find mercurial libraries in 
[/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/  /usr/local/bin
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages] (check your install and
PYTHONPATH). Command line: hg -y debuginstall
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Actually the program runs but the things that annoyed me most is having in the import a red underling for cgi, logging, json beacuse not found by pydev/eclipse. 
idea for this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

On OS X - 10.8.2
Installing mercurial through Python easy_install tool solved the problem

```
easy_install -U mercurial
```

Comment: well I had to do sudo easy_install -U mercurial

Comment: Also sudo-worked for me, but had to update command line tools first (xcode > preferences > download).

Comment: Works also on El Capitan.

Answer (score 14):

I just ran into the same problem, picked a new version (*mercurial-2.2.3+20120707-py2.7-macosx10.7*) from the [Mercurial website](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) and now it works again.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem to this last night after upgrading to **OX 10.9 Mavericks**. I had tried
    `brew install hg` and `brew update` but they didn't work, as everyone's systems are different if you're running homebrew I would recommend running
    `brew doctor`
to see what your particular issue is, in my case I had the following;

> Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
>
> Leaving kegs unlinked
>   can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on those kegs to
>   fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these: mercurial

So to fix my mercurial issue I ran;

`brew link --overwrite mercurial`

Comment: After I installed Mavericks I just run: "easy_install -U mercurial" that solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue.

Reinstalling Mercurial fixed it.  Get it from here: http://mercurial.berkwood.com/

Comment: mm. installed the mercurial-2.2.3_20120707-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Another easy option is to use Homebrew (http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/):

```
brew install hg
```

...worked for me.

Comment: I originally had problems doing it this way and then had to do "brew update".  Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

FYI for others - I was seeing similar errors and had to reinstall setuptools. (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.6c11 if you're not already familiar with it.)

Things seem to work now.

Answer (score 0):

As a macports user I "solved" this by running

```
sudo port install mercurial
```