# Running Mercurial on Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, mercurial, osx-mavericks

Seems that Mercurial doesn't run on Mavericks (Python 3.)  Anyone find a solution.

```
abort: couldn't find mercurial libraries in [
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ 
    /usr/local/bin 
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip 
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7 
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac 
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages 
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python 
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old 
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC 
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
]
(check your install and PYTHONPATH)
```

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar problem to this last night after upgrading to OX 10.9 Mavericks. **Note: I'm using homebrew**, I had tried
    `brew install hg` and `brew update` but they didn't work, as everyone's systems are different I would recommend running
    `brew doctor`
to see what your particular issue is, in my case I had the following;

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these: mercurial
```

So to fix my mercurial issue I ran;

`brew link --overwrite mercurial`

Comment: I updated to macOS Montery and this helped me solve my hg problem.

Answer (score 6):

It all works now with the latest Homebrew.  If you don't have Homebrew installed you can find it at http://brew.sh along with easy instructions.

Once you do have Homebrew, I recommend doing

```
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade
```

To install Mercurial just do

```
$ brew install hg
```

Painless.

Comment: So what's the difference between the "hg" and "mercurial" formulae?

Comment: @AndrewSwan hg is [alias for mercurial formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Aliases/hg)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$ sudo pip uninstall mercurial
```

followed by

```
$ sudo pip install mercurial
```

**EDIT:** If you don't have `pip`, `easy_install pip` first.

Answer (score 4):

Mavericks does ship with python 2.7.5 installed, so Mercurial should run just fine.  You probably just need to fix or redo your install if the path to python changed.

Comment: Yeah, I just re-ran the installer  http://mercurial.berkwood.com and it works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads
The mercurial 2.8-rc update seems to work as well. (website was down earlier)

Answer (score 1):

Only way is to install mercurial is to download this zipfile. It is for osx 10.9 and it works https://www.mercurial-scm.org/mac/binaries/Mercurial-2.9.2-py2.7-macosx10.9.zip

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo easy_install -U mercurial
```

Taken from here: [Mountain Lion update and mercurial libraries python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797761/mountain-lion-update-and-mercurial-libraries-python)